# Hogan, reference file in sub directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, hogan.js

Using either partials or template inheritance, is it really impossible to reference a `.mustache` file from a sub directory?

In other words, having a directory structure like

```
|- views
||- templates
|||- base.mustache
||- somePage.mustache
```

where `somePage.mustache` is something along the lines of

```
{{< templates/base }}
 {{$content}}
  ...
 {{/content}}
{{/ template/super }}
```

or

```
{{> templates/base}}
...
```

Both things work if the base mustache file isn't in a subdirectory, but don't work with the `"templates/"` addition. Is this truly not possible using Hogan.js or am I missing something... because I have tried any and all logical variations I could think of... And the official spec isn't really addressing how this is supposed to work clearly.